# Sum of each row in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to find sum of each row in Crystal Report.
My data is here.

```
Name    P1    P2    P3    Total
A       2      3     4     9
B       1      5     6     12
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just create formula, with content like `{mytable.P1} + {mytable.P2} + {mytable.P3}`

Comment: I already finish trying it. but it show only blank data.

Comment: Do you have any NULL values in your data? If yes, then you need to convert these values to 0 - use `if isnull({mytable.P1}) then 0 else {mytable.P1}` for example.

Comment: yes. I solved my problem yesterday. I edited formula like that.   'WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar mySum;
If not IsNull({@Data1}) then mySum := {@Data1} else mySum := 0;
If not IsNull({@Data2}) then mySum := mySum + {@Data2};
If not IsNull({@Data3}) then mySum := mySum + {@Data3};
mySum'   Anyway thanks your help. :)